# Returning XML From C# WebAPI (Formatting Issues)

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

I'm calling an XML API from my C# Web API.

The response from the XML API should be returned to the end user initiating the request.

Currently the formatting appears to be broken. When you call the XML API directly it returns as expected, however, my C# API returns the response as just one 'lump' string.

Do I need to deserialize this into an object to get it to a better output?

```
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.BaseAddress = $"https://{urlBase}";
            wc.Headers.Add(AuthorizationHeader, authorization);
            result = wc.DownloadString(urlPath);

        }

        return result;
```

[image: Postman Output]

When I look at the calls that the application makes to the XMLAPI using Fiddler I can see that the response from the XMLAPI has the correct formatting applied to it. However, when this is returned from my C# API the formatting appears to be broken.

[image]

In the Application_Start I've forced the application to use XMLMediaTypeFormatter over JSON, this does not appear to have worked:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: What type is returned from the method where your code is placed? It is obvious that it is being serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following which should return a list of XElement.  I can see from the black out code if your results just have innertext or you have attributes as well

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = "";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);
            XElement applist = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = applist.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> apps = doc.Descendants(ns + "app").ToList();
        }
    }
}
```